# Grid with ruler for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, rulers

I am quite new to WPF Development, and am currently developing a WPF Application, for which I require a **grid control with a pixels ruler** as below:

[image]

The above picture has been taken from the RadDiagramRuler control of Telerik WPF Controls, which I obviously cannot use as it's not free. Thus I thought of developing my own similar type of a control. So I created a grid and by using some lines, I was able to get a grid, which I will modify according to my requirements later, as below:

[image]

Now I have the requirement of adding a **ruler with Pixels** to this grid as available in the telerik control. Is there any method I can do this? I Would really appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: well..I have tried to incorporate the ruler available in http://www.orbifold.net/default/wpf-ruler/ but haven't got any luck as it doesn't have pixels as a unit. It only has centimeters and inches.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. You should show the code you did to achieve this and explain what you've tried and what has / hasn't worked.